# Angular 8 app: window.open in new window always redirects to index.html

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular-ui-router, aws-amplify, window.open

I have set up my app with a  tag that has a directive attached to it that will call window.open want my app to open in a new window at a path in my routes

```
window.open(
      '/my-path',
      '_blank',
      'height=550,width=1400'
    );
```

This all works perfectly fine in localhost, but for some reason, when I push into dev, the new window always wants to redirect to index.html and just bounces me to the root, rather than going to /my-path.

Any idea on what I might be missing?

Comment: Does your dev URL path is different from local ? Eg: Local: localhost:4200/my-path and Dev: your-domain.tld/webapp/my-path ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos, dev and local path are exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess (since the problem could have various causes...) that your server tries to handle the request for the child route, but this should be done on the client by Angular.

You must configure your server to fallback to `index.html` for all requests.

Example Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Example Nginx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

More details in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml).

**Update for AWS:**

AWS Amplify redirects per default to `index.html` when a 404 error would occur, but this is a simple redirect. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa):

> Most SPA frameworks support HTML5 history.pushState() to change browser location without triggering a server request. This works for users who begin their journey from the root (or /index.html), but fails for users who navigate directly to any other page. Using regular expressions, the following example sets up a 200 rewrite for all files to index.html except for the specific file extensions specified in the regular expression.

The following settings should work for AWS Amplify:

```
// Original address
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>

// destination
/index.html

// Redirect Type
200
```

Comment: yes, I think this is it.... my Angular app deploy through AWS amplify (which uses Cloudfront), help on doing redirects (404 in this case I think) is here for anyone else: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html

Comment: Actually I do have (by default in Amplify) a redirect to index.html on 404's... and I can see this redirect to index.html path happening, however the routing does not continue to "/my-path"

Comment: Yeah but this is a simple redirect and no rewrite. I still guess I'm right with the cause of the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: Did you find out the cause of your problem? If so, mind to post an answer?

Comment: Yes, it was a case of changing the 404 redirect to a rewrite, thank you!